# STI causing an issue when running application locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am currently working on a Ruby on Rails v4 application.

I created a single table inheritance for two sub-users, `buyer` and `seller`, inheriting from the main `user` table. Since doing that there seems to be an issue when running the application at localhost:3000.

When signing up as a new user I get the following error on the browser page:

```
NoMethodError in Home#main
Showing /Users//Development/secret-project/app/views/layouts/home.html.erb where line #84 raised:
undefined method `seller' for User: 0x00000105714bb0
```

Here's the code from home.html.erb:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`
```

***line #84***     `<%= render_navigation :context => (current_user.blank? ? :guest : :user) %>
                <%= render_navigation :expand_all => true, :context => :auth %>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->`

The browser also gave the following details:

```
app/views/layouts/home.html.erb:84:in '_app_views_layouts_home_html_erb___4408338611430956041_2173428480'
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `main'
```

The home_controller code is:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def main
    @search = Search.new
    @jobs = Product.where("")

    render :layout => 'home'
  end

  def index
    page = params.has_key?(:page)? params[:page].to_i : 1
    per_page = 20
  end

  def contact
     redirect_to :contact
  end
end
```

What have I not updated or done? The only thing I can work out is line 84 is incorrect. I'm thinking it could need to be changed to:

```
<%= render_navigation :context => (current_user.blank? ? :guest : :user : :seller : :buyer) %>
```

When creating a new user they are not stored as a `Seller` by default and this is what confuses me.

Does my change make sense or am I in the wrong location completely?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Something to remember is that Stack Overflow is a reference site, not a social site. When asking a question, try to follow the average look and feel of questions in your formatting, and don't bother with emoticons. Think of a slightly kinder and gentler encyclopedia, or something along the lines of Wikipedia, and you'll do well.

Comment: Where does `render_navigation` come from?

Comment: @nicooga It has only come up in two of my view files when searching for the code within the entire application folder. Is it not an inbuilt command of some kind?

Comment: I don't think so. Google sent me here https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation. Whoever wrote the code before you is probably using this gem to render navigation. Check it out, it may throw some insight on whats wrong.

Comment: @nicooga You are spot on! After looking in the Gemfile I found https://github.com/ShPakvel/simple_navigation_renderers which looks like the last coder has used to simplify the job to split the different user's views and features. Do you believe this will cause many future issues and is there a better way to get the job done? Thanks Nicooga!

Answer (score 0):

**I'd use good ol' polymorphism here.**

The last of your lines is weird, as it branches off into 4 paths from just one condition. It's not even merely impossible, it's a syntax error. But it can be rewritten:

```
<%= render_navigation :context => (current_user.blank? ? :guest : current_user.role) %>
```

Of course, it won't just work on its own. You'd need to define `role` first, start with `User`

```
def role
  :user
end
```

In subclasses, override it:

```
def role
  :buyer # or :seller, in the other class
end
```

This is an architectural example of how to make use of STI. In this exact case, this can be solved pretty quickly even without overriding:

```
def role
  class.name.underscore.to_sym
end
```

It does take some extra computations though. You've been warned. You could also toss this implementation right into the view. `render_navigation` looks pretty much like a **black box** to me, I can't tell if there's a better way to handle this. If you provide more details on what it is, let me know so I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I added this to the `User` Class in models:       `def seller?
      self.user_type == 'seller'
    end

      def buyer?
     self.user_type == 'buyer'
   end`
Does this make sense? It works again with the STI classes `Buyer` and `Seller` but that's because it's using the old methods. The last coder just put `user_type` as a column in the `User` table to differentiate between the two. I'm told STI is the proper way to deal with the sub user classes `Buyer` and `Seller`?

Comment: @RubyMax STI is by definition meant for subclasses sharing their parent's table. That is **yes**. Keep in mind though, that you still have inheritance from Ruby.